# How to calculate the time of a listview render in WPF

Tags: listview, time, rendering

I have a ListView and I am giving the itemssource of the listview to a object of 85000 rows , how could I calculate the rendering time of just the listview with out calculating the database call time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question depends a lot on if your ListView is using virtualization or not and how you are assigning the ItemsSource. Whether you are using a CollectionViewSource for sorting and grouping would matter too, however if we assume you are binding to a model property where the result is assigned you can start a timer there and measure until the last LastViewItem becomes visible. If you are actually trying to debug performance, use a profiler.